# EC2 inbound custom ip rule not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up a testing website on EC2 which can only be accessed internally. What I am trying to do is ask every one to give me their public ip. (By googling the word 'ip') Then I add a rule to the EC2 security group. (Add a rule Type=All TCP, protocol=TCP, port=0-65535, source=[public ip]/32) However this doesn't seem work. They still cannot access the website.

For example, if I make the source to be "Anywhere", I can access the website. If I just change it to "custom ip" with the same ip + "/32", I cannot access the website. Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Looks right to me. Do you want TCP or HTTP? Settings to 'All traffic' should unlock everything for the IP, so you can check if the setup is wrong.

Comment: Setting it to All traffic doesn't work. The only thing I can make it work is setting source to Anywhere. But the purpose is to only allow certain ips to access the website.

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without more details. You have a public IP/DNS for your EC2 instance? Your security group is attached to that EC2 instance? If so, what you did above should work.